# Adding random tiny flakes (gold) to appear suspended in gel

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'd like to know the best solution on adding tiny floating flakes in a gel solution. I suspect array might get me there but everything I've tried is much to uniform[image]

Comment: Textures would be best way i can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Probably particle system with texture set to influence on particles' density.. This depends quite a bit on necessary amount of details though.

Comment: Given the advances in Blender 2.8, is this question now closer to being answered?